# Escape variable in New-ADUser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to use a variable in the portion of the arguments where the `targetAddress` and `proxyAddresses` are specified.

This is the command now with the email addresses hard coded with user "newUser". How to replace that with variable `$accountName`?

```
New-ADUser -Name $fullName -AccountPassword $PWord -OtherAttributes @{
  'extensionAttribute1' = 'Acme Corp';
  'msExchExtensionCustomAttribute1' = 'Acme Corp';
  'proxyAddresses' = 'SMTP:newUser@acmecorp.com',
                     'smtp:newUser@acmecorp.mail.onmicrosoft.com';
  'targetAddress' = 'SMTP:newUser@acmecorp.mail.onmicrosoft.com'
}
```

Comment: User Principal Names (UPN) may look like e-mail addresses, but they're not. Don't confuse the two.

Answer (score 0):

Well, -OtherAttributes is just a hash, so you just put a variable in place of the hash value.  I'd strongly recommend breaking your hash out, and "splat" it, e.g.:

```
[String[]]  $proxyAddresses  = @( 'SMTP:newUser@acmecorp.com','smtp:newUser@acmecorp.mail.onmicrosoft.com' );

[String]    $targetAddress = 'SMTP:newUser@acmecorp.mail.onmicrosoft.com';

[Hashtable] $otherAttributes = @{ extensionAttribute1 = 'Acme Corp';
                                  msExchExtensionCustomAttribute1 = 'Acme Corp'; 
                                  proxyAddresses = $proxyAddresses;
                                  targetAddress  = $targetAddress;
                                };

try {
    New-ADUser -Name $fullName -AccountPassword $PWord -OtherAttributes @otherAttributes;
    }
catch [<exception type>] {
    }
```

Comment: The type casts are pointless. Also, you splat arrays/hashes when you want to pass an argument list to a cmdlet or external command (see [`about_Splatting`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx)). In this case the parameter itself expects a hash, so just pass it regularly (`-OtherAttributes $otherAttributes`).

Comment: Simon:  I'm close to having a solution.  Just one problem with the Proxy Addresses attribute..  The active directory object instead of holding the two email addresses has both addresses in one entry separated by a space. And I pass $otherAttributes the way Ansgar suggested.

Comment: Here is how I have the relevant lines:
`[String[]]  $proxyAddresses  = @( 'SMTP:' + $accountName + '@acmecorp.com','smtp:' + $accountName + '@acmecorp.mail.onmicrosoft.com' );`
and
    `[Hashtable] $otherAttributes = @{ extensionAttribute1 = 'Acme';
                                  msExchExtensionCustomAttribute1 = 'Acme'; 
                                  proxyAddresses = $proxyAddresses;
                                  targetAddress  = $targetAddress;
                                };`

Comment: Good spot on cmdlet expecting a hash.  Disagree about static type assignments (not casting, BTW).  In an enterprise environment, static types serve two purposes: i) we get powershell to pick up on our mistakes and don't allow dynamic typing to cause strange results that could take hours/days to resolve; and ii) it's immediately obvious to others that may have to maintain that the code what the developer was trying to do.  I've been at the smelly end of the stick on this one, where, for example, a value has overflowed, been dynamically "re-typed", then caused an exception down the path.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with... it works... but is not pretty

```
$proxyEmail1 = 'SMTP:' + $accountName + '@acmecorp.com'
$proxyEmail2 = 'smtp:' + $accountName + '@acmecorp.mail.onmicrosoft.com'


[String]    $targetAddress = 'SMTP:' + $accountName + '@acmecorp.mail.onmicrosoft.com';

[Hashtable] $otherAttributes = @{ extensionAttribute1 = 'Acme';
                              msExchExtensionCustomAttribute1 = 'Acme'; 
                              targetAddress  = $targetAddress;
                            };

New-ADUser  -Name $fullName  -OtherAttributes $otherAttributes  [lots of stuff redacted]

Get-ADUser $accountName | Set-ADUser -Add @{proxyAddresses=$proxyEmail1}
Get-ADUser $accountName | Set-ADUser -Add @{proxyAddresses=$proxyEmail2}
```